# Add custom menu items to the Finder context menu

Tags: cocoa, macos, reverse-engineering, finder

How do I add custom menu items to the context menu for files in Finder?

Unfortunately, most of the information out on the Internet and on Stack Overflow doesn't work in 10.6 or are too limited. Automator, for example, doesn't allow you to create items dynamically or create submenus.

I know it's still possible to do this sort of thing because Dropbox and FolderGlance both do similar things. Does anyone know how they implemented this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm fairly certain dropbox uses [mach_inject](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_star). As to how you use that project to accomplish this... that's what I'm trying to figure out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded FolderGlance and it appears to use an osax (Scripting Addition) bundle to inject code into the Finder process. This is definitely fragile and unsupported.

As far as I am aware the only legit way to add items to the Finder contextual menu is to create a Service, but that doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

In macOS 10.10+, [Finder Sync Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html) can be used to add items to the Finder context menu. This is how modern versions of Dropbox and similar apps customize the right-click menu.

[image: Finder Sync Extension in Context Menu]

For those just seeking to use the functionality, not develop their own app extension, I've released a Mac app that allows for arbitrary customization of a Finder Sync Extension:

[Service Station - Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/service-station/id1503136033?ls=1/)

[image]

Comment: Hi, In the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH15-SW1) it is mentioned that you need to implement the `menuForMenuKind:` method passing the menu kind to it as an argument. But it doesn't say from where I should be calling the method with the parameter and how to set an icon like you have done. Can you please post some sample code? That wll be really helpful.

Comment: @Isuru When you implement `menuForMenuKind:` you'll be overriding the default implementation of the method. No need to *call* the method yourself... Finder will call it when it needs to, and now get your custom menu rather than the default. Be sure to add a new Finder Sync Extension **Target** to your app. When you do, Xcode will insert a bunch of boilerplate code that you can then modify.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, Dropbox now uses [mach_star](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_star) for code injection. Obviously this is a fragile solution. If you look through their version history, many of their updates are to fix finder integration.

Answer (score 1):

Up to to the OS X 10.9.x only injecting code to Finder process via mach_inject was a solution (and even Dropbox did that).
However since 10.10 there are Finder plugins, which can customize context menus, add buttons to Toolbar and put overlays over file icons.

Answer (score 0):

They used CFPlugIn to add their menu items.

More on it here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPlugInRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Can you give any more detail about how `CFPlugin` can be used to accomplish this?

Comment: This is the "old way", and only worked in Leopard (not Snow Leopard) and older versions of OSX.