# How Dropbox adds menu item to Finder's context menu?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have read many answers on similar questions but all suggest that they are no longer possible. I have OSX 10.9 and see Dropbox managing to do that.

[image: Dropbox demo]

Above screenshot is Finder's context menu. How to add menu items to Finder's context menu as shown above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Write OS X Finder plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294335/how-to-write-os-x-finder-plugin)

Comment: That answer is from 2009. My intention for reposting this is to know if anything has changed since then. I also found another similar thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461643/add-custom-menu-items-to-the-finder-context-menu from 2011.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom menu items to the Finder context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461643/add-custom-menu-items-to-the-finder-context-menu)

Answer (score 5):

While an old question, I recently had the same question and after a bit of digging I discovered that Dropbox is currently using Finder Sync, which appears to have a feature set perfect for what Dropbox does.

See the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html

`garcon.appex` inside `Dropbox.app` is the Finder Sync extension based on the contents of the `Info.plist` in the appex package:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.FinderSync</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>EFFinderExtension</string>
</dict>
```

From the documentation:

> With a Finder Sync extension you register one or more folders for the
>   system to monitor. Your Finder Sync extension then sets badges,
>   labels, and contextual menus for any items in the monitored folders.
>   You can also use the extension point’s API to add a toolbar button to
>   the Finder window or a sidebar icon for the monitored folder.